# Instalación Linux , pantalla negra despues de instalar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Soy nueva en linux y estoy intentando instalar alguna distro de ubuntu o debian en una pc industrial que va a ejecutar una app java para el control de una maquinaria agrícola. La pc es una Hasar CTC-1002. 
Intenté instalar Ubuntu 14, Xubuntu 16.04 y ahora por ultimo debian 9.5, en los tres casos tengo el mismo problema, inicia la bios, abre el inicio de ubuntu y después deja de dar señal de video, pantalla negra.

Solo en xubuntu logré ver el escritorio algunas veces, pero luego de apagar la pc, la encendía y entonces otra vez me pasaba este error de pantalla negra.

Probe cambiar muchas de las configuraciones de la bios (Que es una bios award) : 
DIsco ACHI, IDE
Legacy enabled y disabled
Block mode enabled y disabled 
Diferentes resoluciones de video
Nada de eso funciona...

Gracias desde ya, todos los aportes serán bienvenidos.

Comment: Normalmente si se queda en negro la pantalla puedes probar a pulsar CTR+ALT+F5 (prueba con todas las teclas de funcionaF2, F3..), hasta que salga en modo texto. Si sale, el problema es de configuración de las X, si no aparece nada, intenta arrancar con un livecd, prueba si funciona y si es así, instala la versión del livecd.

Comment: ¿Estás instalando solo modo caracter, o estás intentando cargar las X? ¿Puedes arrancar con un live CD/USB en modo caracter y tienes el mismo efecto? ¿luego de eso, puedes arrancar las X normalmente?

Comment: Hola! No estaba instalando solo en modo caracter, sino con interfaz grafica. Les cuento que con el transcurso de los días llegue a la conclusión de que mi hardware de video solo es compatible con los drivers de video del kernel 3.13 de linux, y es con el unico que funciona bien pero no permite girar la pantalla. Hay otros drivers genéricos como los del kernel siguiente, que funcionan pero hacen que la maquina ande más lento, gracias por las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

- Imagino que usaste un memoria booteable y estás haciendo un dual boot con windows, en caso de que si verifica la partición de tu disco duro y si elegiste correctamente el tipo de partición del disco.
- Si verificaste en tipo de partición o vas a instalar completamente Ubunut y  tienes tarjeta de video Nvidia sigue los siguientes pasos:

  1. Cuando inicie el GRUB presiona e
  2. Muevete con las flechas hasta "quiet splash" y reempleza con "no splash" o "nomodeset".
  3. Luego de cambiar por alguno de los dos presiona Ctrl + x. Luego se iniciará el sistema.
- Algunas veces el sistema inicia con el brillo mínimo. El cual, sin exagerar, deja la pantalla casi a oscura. Intenta subir el brillo.

Comment: No es un boot compartido, solo quiero instalar linux en la pc. No tengo tarjeta nvidia, pero de todas maneras probe hacer lo que me dijiste, pero el problema no se solucionó, y sigo sin poder iniciar el so. Gracias!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Si puedes instalar tu distribución, una vez que inicies tu distro, trata de entrar sin el modo gráfico, es decir, presiona la combinación de teclas ctrl (el izquierdo) + alt (el izquierdo) + fn, siendo n un valor del rango desde 1 hasta 12. Ahí te va a pedir usuario y contraseña. Con eso al menos sabrás que el único problema es el gráfico pero ya podrás entrar desde la terminal.

Otra cosa que podrías hacer para entrar es entrando en modo de recuperación (*recovery mode*). Cuando se enciendas la computadora, en el menú del GRUB. Lo mismo que en la opción anterior, al menos sabrás que el problema es gráfico.

Algo que podrías hacer, si es que logras entrar, en el caso de ubuntu, es

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Si no puedes iniciar ni el live cd, puedes intentar con algo de [este](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) enlace, que es algo como lo que sugirió @ivan-gonzalez, y si no te funciona puedes tratar de usar Windows y dentro de windows una máquina virtual (si es que de verdad te urge un SO de tipo GNU/Linux).